# groovy copy files with same last modified date

Tags: file, groovy, directory, copy

Hi I want to copy a file from 1 directory to another, but the date has to be the same. so when the last modified date in the fromdirectory is 14:35, I want it to be the same in the todirectory.

How can I do this using groovy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Using AntBuilder

```
new AntBuilder().copy ( file                 : 'path/to/source', 
                        tofile               : 'path/to/destination', 
                        preservelastmodified : 'true' )
```

### Using Java/Groovy File API

```
def source = new File ('path/to/source')
def destination = new File ('path/to/destination')

source.withInputStream { is -> 
  destination << is 
}

destination.lastModified = source.lastModified()
```

Comment: when I use your code  using java/groovy file api, my jar-file which I want to copy changes of content

Comment: I updated my answer to use use an `InputStream` instead of `Writable`, which should do a binary copy from the source file. Keep in mind that the `<<` is a file append operation, so if the destination file already exists, this will append the source content at the end of the destination content.